# Capybara/Webkit: 'keypress' vs 'keydown'

Tags: jquery, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my Rails app, I am using this jQuery to prevent a form from being submitted when the user presses 'enter' in an input field:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.which == '13') {
    return false;
  }
})
```

I wrote a test in Capybara to make sure the form was not being submitted (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622022/rails-capybara-test-that-form-does-not-submit)), and had a hell of a time getting the test to work properly.  Eventually I discovered that the jQuery function had to target a `keydown` event, not `keypress`.  It works wonderfully now.

This makes me a bit uncomfortable, because I know that `keypress` should work just as well, and I know that it actually does work from trying it manually in the browser.  But if I want to have a working test for this behavior, I have to do it with `keydown`.

This is the command that I'm sending to Webkit in my integration test:

```
page.driver.browser.execute_script "var e = jQuery.Event('keydown'); e.which = 13; $('#shift_employee').trigger( e );"
```

It goes without saying that when I change the jQuery function to handle `keypress` instead of `keydown`, I also change the Ruby line above to trigger a `keypress` event instead of a `keydown` event.  But the test fails unless I use `keydown`.

So what's the deal?  Is this a Webkit issue?  Should I not worry about it, as long as the test is working and the form is not being submitted?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent submitting on pressing enter? I'd view that as the primary problem.

Comment: @KevinB : I second that!

Comment: However, more relevant to the question, I would lean toward using keydown simply because it happens first. keypress requires the user to release the key, while keydown catches it immediately.

Comment: You can add to submit button click event: `$('form').data('allow', true);` and in form submit event `if($('form').data('allow'))`

Comment: Long story, but I actually didn't intend to do it this way. I'll probably change it back after fixing some other stuff, but I wanted to make sure I could test it in the meantime. When I found that I couldn't, it became an obsession, not because it's so important to prevent submitting the form, but because it's such a simple thing that I felt my inability to test it was a major gap in my knowledge. Most of my problem, though, was not with the keydown/keypress issue, but with the issue mentioned in the other question linked above.

Comment: Kryzsiek, that's an interesting suggestion, but my question is more about what's going on with capybara-webkit, not how to prevent form submission.

Comment: **Update:** I just realized that the title of this question was really ambiguous.  I've changed it to be more relevant to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are over-thinking the problem.  The form gets submitted on `enter` because you have a submit button inside the form.  So if you don't want that behavior, you have the following option:

Remove the submit button from your form.  If you need the button for other actions, you can simply create a non-submitting element that looks like a button and fire off a `submit()` when clicked.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a submit button. The form is submitted via AJAX when you click a link. That being said, I will probably not stick with this approach in the long run. I just want to understand why it is necessary for me to use 'keydown' to get my test to pass with Capybara/Webkit.